# Navigate routing for different types of users in web application in angular ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to have different pages in my web application when I am logged in as just user and logged in as admin. I have made a authservice where I take the value isAdmin from my user object and I have also a method to take from auth.service.ts ... What should I add in my login.component.ts to take the isAdmin parameter? Now in my console shows:

```
 undefined                   auth.service.ts:41 
 [token.value...]            auth.service.ts:78
 false                       auth.service.ts:85
 true                        login.component.ts:51
```

It seems that doesn't wait to take the isAdmin value and always goes to admin page when I logged in as user and as admin. What should I add in my login.component.ts?

```
//auth.service.ts
getIsAuth() {
return  this.isAuthenticated;
}

getUserAdmin(){
console.log(this.isAdmin);
return this.isAdmin;
}


// auth.guard.ts
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
  const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
  const isAdmin= this.authService.getUserAdmin();
  if (!isAuth) {
    this.router.navigate(['observatory/api/login']);
  }
    else{
    if (!isAdmin){
      this.router.navigate(['observatory/api/user']);
    }
    else if (isAdmin){
      this.router.navigate(['observatory/api/admin']);
    }
  }
  return isAuth;

}

 //login.component.ts
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;


    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    this.authService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value);
    this.loading = true;
    this.isAdmin= this.authService.getUserAdmin();
    this.authListenerSubs = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe(async isAdmin => {
           this.isAdmin= await isAdmin;
        console.log(this.isAdmin);
        if (!this.isAdmin){
            this.router.navigate(['/user']);
          }
        else{
            this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
          }
      }); 


 //auth.service.ts: fuction-login
 login( username: string,  password: string) {
var user: User = {  username: username, password: password };
this.http
  .post<any>("http://localhost:3000/api/auth",user, {observe:'response'})
  .subscribe((res) => {
    const token = res.headers.get('X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH');
    console.log(token);
    this.token = token;
    if (token!==null) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = res.body._id;
      this.isAdmin=res.body.isAdmin;
      this.userAdmin=res.body.isAdmin;
      console.log(this.userAdmin);
      this.username=res.body.username;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
      this.saveAuthData(token, this.userId,this.username, this.isAdmin); 
    }
  });

  getUserAdmin(){
console.log(this.userAdmin);
return this.userAdmin;
```

}

```
  //app-routing.ts
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'observatory/api/login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'observatory/api/register', component: RegisterComponent },
  {path: 'observatory/api/logout', component:LogoutComponent},
{path: 'observatory/api', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'observatory/api/user',component:UserComponent},
{path:'observatory/api/admin', component:AdminComponent},
{path:'observatory/api/users', component:UsersComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},

// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', component:NotFoundComponent}
```

];

Comment: could you add the routing of your application? to see how is it structured

Comment: Since you have isAdmin and isAuth flags, you could just render appropriate components for guest and admin (or route to different paths) conditionally, couldn't you?

Comment: what is the method `this.authService.login` returning? I'd bet you need to subscribe to the result to effectively be able to navigate consequently.

Comment: #lukbrt Ι add it in the login.component but I can't change the page of login. It is stacked there.

Comment: Add navigation in your subscription callback (this.router.navigateByUrl('/observatory/api/user'); etc)

Comment: where should I add this navigation? And only this routing will always send me to the user page, although I want to have different pages for users and admin